# SQL order by specific values

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have the following data in SQL SERVER DB

[image]

on which an ordering is needed.

The ordering is to be done on specific value of priority

- First ascending value of priority 1,2,3,...
- Second the row with priority 0 is shown last

After ordering on priority, rows with the same priority will be ordered alphabetically

So the expected output is

[image]

I have done the following code

```
SELECT SERVICELONGNAME,SERVICEPRIORITYID FROM SERVICE

ORDER BY  

  CASE  
            WHEN SERVICEPRIORITYID > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1   
            END
,SERVICELONGNAME ASC
enter code here
```

But in this case the rows with priority 0 is shown at the bottom but for SERVICEPRIORITYID  1,2,3,4 it is jumbled up.

Please can someone tell me what changes are required to match with the required output?

Comment: You query seems good, except your second `order by` is `SERVICELONGNAME` instead of `SERVICEPRIORITYID`

Comment: @HoneyBadger This doesn't sort the values alphabetically having same priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT SERVICELONGNAME
    ,SERVICEPRIORITYID
FROM SERVICE
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN SERVICEPRIORITYID > 0
            THEN SERVICEPRIORITYID
        ELSE 2147483647 -- Int max value
        END
    ,SERVICELONGNAME ASC enter code here
```

When `SERVICEPRIORITYID` is greater then 0 order by `SERVICEPRIORITYID` else order by int max value.

Comment: Thanks!  bit difficult to read the code but never mind, this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT SERVICELONGNAME,SERVICEPRIORITYID 
FROM SERVICE
ORDER BY  CASE  
            WHEN SERVICEPRIORITYID=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,SERVICELONGNAME ASC
```

Comment: This is still giving jumbled values but 0 is at the bottom row as expected